# Higher order nonlinear stress definition

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain, non-linear-systems

For the nonlinear case, I often find the following definition for the mechanical stress:

$$ \sigma=E_2\epsilon+E_3\epsilon^2$$

The parameters $E_2$ and $E_3$ are called "elastic modulus" or "huang coefficient". Where exactly is the difference to the linear modulus of elasticity $E$? How can this be interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpretation of $\sigma = E_2\varepsilon+E_3\varepsilon^2$ is that we are considering nonlinear elasticity (often associated with the anharmonicity of the interatomic potential of real crystals strained to large amounts) expanded via strain terms. That's why the $\varepsilon^2$ term appears. However, it's not obvious what $E_2$ refers to without more information. Here's why.

In comparison, generalized Hooke's Law for an isotropic material for any loading is

$$\sigma_{ij}=\frac{E}{1+\nu}\varepsilon_{ij}+\frac{\nu E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}(\varepsilon_{11}+\varepsilon_{22}+\varepsilon_{33})\delta_{ij},$$

where $E$ is Young's modulus, $\nu$ is Poisson's ratio, and the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and 0 otherwise.

1. One option is that the equation $\sigma=E_2\varepsilon+E_3\varepsilon^2$ describes only one normal stress ($\sigma_{11}$, say) and one normal strain ($\varepsilon_{11}$) and assumes an elongated geometry in which the lateral stresses are zero so that $\varepsilon_{22}=\varepsilon_{33}=-\nu\varepsilon_{11}$ (representing Poisson contraction). Here, generalized Hooke's Law simplifies to $\sigma_{11}=E\varepsilon_{11}$. To this we add the nonlinear additional term.
2. Another option (**if $E_2=\lambda+2\mu$ as you note in the comments, where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the Lamé constants, then this is the correct option**) is that the lateral strains $\varepsilon_{22}=\varepsilon_{33}=0$, as could occur inside a material. $E_2$ is then the so-called P-wave modulus $\frac{E(1-\nu)}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}$, as can be derived easily from generalized Hooke's Law above.
3. Another option is that the equation describes one shear stress ($\sigma_{12}$, say), and one tensorial shear strain ($\varepsilon_{12}$). Here, generalized Hooke's Law simplifies to $\sigma_{12}=\frac{E}{1+\nu}\varepsilon_{12}$.
4. Another option is that the equation describes the shear stress and the *engineering* shear strain $\gamma$, which is twice the tensorial shear strain. Here, generalized Hooke's Law simplifies to $\sigma=\frac{E}{2(1+\nu)}\gamma=G\gamma$, where $G$ is the shear modulus.

And many more elastic moduli exist (e.g., the biaxial modulus, the plane-strain modulus) under various other loading configurations. Without more context, therefore, we can only say that $E_2$ represents one of these elastic moduli.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. In the one-dimensional case, this equation describes the strain behavior of a lattice structure during a dislocation.

Comment: I also found the following excerpt from a [paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5046640): 
 _First, we consider the intrinsic acoustic nonlinearity. For elastic solids with quadratic nonlinearity, the one-dimensional stress-strain relation in the x-direction can be expressed through the first Piola-Kirchhoff stress_ $$\sigma = E_2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+E_3(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2$$ _where u is the particle displacement and E2 and E3 are the second- and third-order Huang’s coefficients..._

Comment: Within a solid, $E_2$ is likely to correspond to the so-called P-wave modulus $\frac{E(1-\nu)}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}$, which is the stress required to obtain a unit strain $\varepsilon_{11}$ when $\varepsilon_{22}$ and $\varepsilon_{33}$ are constrained to be zero by the surrounding material. (This is easily shown via generalized Hooke's Law above.) I discuss different elastic moduli [here](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/overrating_youngs_modulus.htm).

Comment: In some works $ E_2 = E_3 $ is assumed. This would correspond to your assumption of the Young modulus. Others use $ E_2 $ = $ - E_3 $ or even completely different values, which is even more confusing.

Comment: Young's modulus doesn't incorporate higher-order terms, so whether $E_2=E_3$ or not says nothing about whether $E_2$ corresponds to Young's modulus.

Comment: The explanation with the P-wave modulus and the constrained lateral strains makes sense. This means that the definition of $E_2$ is understandable. How can the moduli $E_3$ be described? I have also found the following definitions with lame constants:
$$ E_2 = \lambda+2\mu $$
$$ E_3 = 3E_2+2(l+ 2m) $$

Comment: The first equation means that $E_2$ is definitely the P-wave modulus, no question. Where did you see the second equation?

Comment: In following [paper] (https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5046640). Is it allowed to send a screenshot?

Comment: Ah, got it. Here, $l$ and $m$ are two of the so-called Murnaghan constants (with $n$ completing the set). The terms $\lambda+2\mu$ and $2l+4m$ are also respectively called $C_{11}$ and $C_{111}$ in the literature, so you'll sometimes see $E_3=3C_{11}+C_{111}$ (e.g., eq. 43 [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0041624X14000134), which contains many useful relations).

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I was looking for. The derivations of the elastic constants are described very well here. Thanks!